# Ionic 4 App click event inside DIV not being fired sometimes

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic4

In the first tab of an Ionic 4 app, a ngx-gauge is shown with some data from server.

Below the gauge, some divs are displayed. Each of those div have a `(click)` function.

The three divs on the bottom work fine. However, the three first divs (CO2, PM2,5 and PM10) are not working properly... To activate the `(click)` event of those 3 divs you might have to click several times, while to activate the `(click)` event of the other 3 divs below (TVOC, Temperature, and Humidity) one click is working fine.

The version of the ngx-gauge is:

```
ngx-gauge@1.0.0-beta.10
```

If I separate the gauge and the divs with many `<br>`, all the 6 divs are working fine with only 1 click.

[image]

Any idea of how to solve this problem?

Comment: Share some of your code (ideally via stackblitz), that way it's easier to reproduce your problem. I reckon it's a small issue but seeing the code would help.

Comment: Share minimal code for reproduction